# NullReference error in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application. I want to insert multiple rows at once into a database table. I am using a database-first approach.

I am facing an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can you guide me how to resolve it?

Here is code of myapp model class:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class tbl_hgt
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public decimal Height { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the myapp view. I guess I have problem in view but not sure

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.tbl_hgt>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "InsertRows";
}

<h2>InsertRows</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertRows", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Height</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Id[" + i + "]")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Name[" + i + "]")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Age[" + i + "]")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Gender[" + i + "]")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Height[" + i + "]")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Weight[" + i + "]")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here is the code of `myapp` controller class. I am not sure should I create one more action method to view.

```
using MyApp.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class myController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult InsertRows(int[] Id, string[] Name, int[] Age, string[] Gender, decimal[] Height, decimal[] Weight)
    {
        // Create a context object to access the database
        using (var db = new Employee_DbEntities())
        {
            // Loop through the arrays and create a new row object for each row

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var row = new tbl_hgt();
                row.Id = Id[i];
                row.Name = Name[i];
                row.Age = Age[i];
                row.Gender = Gender[i];
                row.Height = Height[i];
                row.Weight = Weight[i];

                // Add the row object to the context
                db.tbl_hgt.Add(row);
            }

            // Save the changes to the database
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Return a view or a message to confirm the insertion
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

[image]

I am just learning ASP.NET MVC - please help me to understand this error.

Comment: It seems like parameter `int[] Id` is null here. Please make sure it should not be null and you are passing a value while calling the controller .

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the issue myself. i missed [httpget] action method in controller i was directly calling [httppost] mehtod.
thanks